# How does Jackson get configured for Jersey in Spring Boot (SPI scanning seems to be disabled)

Tags: jackson, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I'm using Spring Boot with Jersey 2. The only media provider is org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson (checked the runtime classpath) so I guess I'm using it for JSON serialization. However, I don't configure it explicitly, but I noticed in JerseyAutoConfiguration#addInitParameters that scanning for SPIs is explicitly disabled with the following line:

```
registration.addInitParameter(CommonProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, "true");
```

The Jackson feature is defined in jersey-media-json-jackson.jar/!META-INF/services/..., but scanning it is disabled.

How does Jackson get configured for Jersey in Spring Boot?

Comment: It would help me a lot if downvoters at least left a comment about what is wrong with the question so that I can improve. I did a fair amount of reading and own investigation, and this is an honest question to better understand the things I'm supposed to use in a project, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, Jackson gets automatically configured in Spring Boot (it just need to find Jackson lib in your classpath).

There are a lot of ways to configuring Jackson as you can see [here in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

If you want to see in details the configuration of Jackson in Spring Boot, take a look at [JacksonAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/lucassaldanha/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java) class.

Comment: I know Jackson is automatically configured, but Jersey must somehow be made aware of Jackson. This is normally done programmatically, by registering JacksonFeature, or by auto-discovery. I didn't find any explicit usage of JacksonFeature, and an explicit disabling of auto-scanning of META-INF/services/*. Also, the documentation mentiones Jackson auto-config in Spring MVC context only. What I'm missing is the 'glue' between Jackson and Jersey.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in JacksonAutoDiscoverable (a Jersey class from jersey-media-json-jackson, and its configure method does get called on first REST resource access. So now I don't understand why this happens as it is disabled by Spring...